# Keep getting the error TypeError: function takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am working on a integration from instagram to telegram bot, it will monitore a user account and every new post, I'll be notified on telegram. I'm creating my tables for this project and stuck on tables creation using SQLAlchemy, anyone already faced these issues?

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, DateTime, Text, Boolean
from config import Base, engine
import uuid


class InstagramImageNoRss(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'instagram_image_norss'
    __table_args__ = {'sqlite_autoincrement': True}
    id = Column(Text, primary_key=True, default=lambda: uuid.uuid4().hex)
    local_path = Column(Text)
    local_path_txt = Column(Text)
    local_path_json = Column(Text)
    comments_path = Column(Text)
    geolocation_path = Column(Text)
    text_data = Column(Text)
    json_data = Column(Text)
    comments_data = Column(Text)
    geolocation_data = Column(Text)
    username = Column(Text)
    sended = Column(Boolean)
    published = Column(DateTime)
    publication_index = Column(Integer)

    def __str__(self):
        import json
        return json.dumps(self.__dict__, default=str)


class InstgaramImageRss(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'instagram_image_rss'
    __table_args__ = {'sqlite_autoincrement': True}
    id = Column(Text, primary_key=True, default=lambda: uuid.uuid4().hex)
    published = Column(DateTime)
    local_name = Column(Text)
    local_path = Column(Text)
    rss_webstagram_id = Column(Text)
    summary = Column(Text)
    media_url = Column(Text)
    image_hash = Column(Text)
    creation_time = Column(DateTime)
    link = Column(Text)
    sended = Column(Boolean)
    username = Column(Text)

    def __str__(self):
        import json
        return json.dumps(self.__dict__, default=str)


class InstagramSubscription(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'instagram_subscription'
    __table_args__ = {'sqlite_autoincrement': True}
    id = Column(Text, primary_key=True, default=lambda: uuid.uuid4().hex)
    username = Column(Text, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    last_check_datetime = Column(DateTime)
    subscribed = Column(Boolean)

    def __str__(self):
        import json
        return json.dumps(self.__dict__, default=str, indent=4)


class Chat(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'chats'
    __table_args__ = {'sqlite_autoincrement': True}
    id = Column(Text, primary_key=True, default=lambda: uuid.uuid4().hex)
    chat_id = Column(Integer)
    admin = Column(Boolean)
    tg_ans = Column(Text)

    def __str__(self):
        import json
        return json.dumps(self.__dict__, default=str, indent=4)

# Error happens here
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Im receiving this following error: **TypeError: function takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)**

Currently using SQLite3 **3.37.2** and PY **3.11.1**

As requested, completely traceback error:

```
File "/workspace/InstagramTelegramBot/InstagramBotDAO.py", line 76, in <module>
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
  File "/workspace/InstagramTelegramBot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 5828, in create_all
    bind._run_ddl_visitor(
  File "/workspace/InstagramTelegramBot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3242, in _run_ddl_visitor
    with self.begin() as conn:
  File "/home/ribeiroo/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/workspace/InstagramTelegramBot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3232, in begin
    with self.connect() as conn:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/workspace/InstagramTelegramBot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3268, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/workspace/InstagramTelegramBot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/workspace/InstagramTelegramBot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3292, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/workspace/InstagramTelegramBot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 421, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self, self._fairy)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/workspace/InstagramTelegramBot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1269, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/workspace/InstagramTelegramBot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 716, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/workspace/InstagramTelegramBot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 403, in _do_get
    c = self._create_connection()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/workspace/InstagramTelegramBot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 393, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/workspace/InstagramTelegramBot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 678, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/workspace/InstagramTelegramBot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 916, in __connect
    )._exec_w_sync_on_first_run(self.dbapi_connection, self)
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/workspace/InstagramTelegramBot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 473, in _exec_w_sync_on_first_run
    self(*args, **kw)
  File "/workspace/InstagramTelegramBot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 487, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "/workspace/InstagramTelegramBot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 704, in on_connect
    do_on_connect(dbapi_connection)
  File "/workspace/InstagramTelegramBot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/pysqlcipher.py", line 145, in on_connect
    super_on_connect(conn)
  File "/workspace/InstagramTelegramBot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/pysqlite.py", line 574, in connect
    fn(conn)
  File "/workspace/InstagramTelegramBot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/pysqlite.py", line 557, in set_regexp
    dbapi_connection.create_function(
TypeError: function takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

Comment: Oh, thats weird! Complete error added as requested

Comment: What does your `create_engine` call look like?

Comment: `create_engine` creates the database. db file and creates the hero table in that database. Which version of python are u using?

Comment: Oh, thats would be incompatibility with PY 3.11.1, I've just installed 3.7 and worked

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this error by installing [pysqlcipher](https://pypi.org/project/pysqlcipher3/) and creating an engine like this:

```py
create_engine('sqlite+pysqlcipher://:password@/so77320976.db'
```

If I install the [sqlcipher3](https://pypi.org/project/sqlcipher3/) driver instead, the error does not occur.